# Get Directions API call ? react-native

Tags: react-native

In many iOS apps I can see a button saying getDirections, which will upon click open an Apple/Google maps with latitude and longitude passed as destination.

I have my `TouchableHighlight` button with lat and lng ready. What API endpoint do I need to call in `onPress` callback to open Apple maps with my coordinates as route destination?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To link to another application, such as Maps, use [LinkingIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linkingios.html):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linkingios.html

```
// Replace lat and long with your own decimal latitude and longitude values
var url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=<lat>,<long>';
LinkingIOS.openURL(url);
```

For maps the URL scheme is just the same as from a standard Obj-C app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: LinkingIOS has been deprecated.  Use [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) instead.

Comment: To actually start a navigation, use `http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=<lat>,<long>` for iOS and `http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=<lat>,<long>` for Android.

Answer (score 7):

To link to another application, and open itinerary as Maps, use this function:

```
export function openDirections(latitude, longitude) {
    Platform.select({
        ios: () => {
            Linking.openURL('http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=' + latitude + ',' + longitude);
        },
        android: () => {
            Linking.openURL('http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + latitude + ',' + longitude);
        }
    })();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [Geolocation API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#content):

```
// Get position once
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (initialPosition) => this.setState({initialPosition}), // success callback
    (error) => alert(error.message), // failure callback
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000} // options
);

// Repeatedly track position
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) => {
  this.setState({lastPosition});
});
```

You can then use the position and display it however you want, perhaps in a [MapView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html#content).

Comment: hmm, may be i am not clear i'll edit my question , i already have lat lng and touchable highlight button on press of this i want to open iosmap. MapView is just view with a red pin for location/annotation .